# Net Core: Find Application Assembly Location from Integration Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit

We have a API Real Application which is running following code to get the Assembly Directory.

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location

Result:
C:\\OriginalApplicationAPI\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.2
```

Now we are running an Integration Xunit project, which is running the Startup, appsettings, etc from the original project.

Running this code from the Integration test project renders,

```
C:\\Users\\..\\.nuget\\packages\\microsoft.testplatform.testhost\\15.9.0\\lib\\netstandard1.5"
```

How do I refer to the OriginalApplicationAPI Assembly Location from test project? Is it by namespace or project reference?

Thanks,

Comment: Using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` should give you path to the correct assembly path.

Comment: well what if its not executing? I just need way to refer to other assemblies by project reference or namespace

Comment: Well :-) you will need to know of a Type that is in the assembly, let's pretend `App.MyClass` is defined in the assembly. You can call `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(App.MyClass)).Location`. You can't do it off `namespace` as a namespace can exist across multiple assemblies. You need an actual Type to get the correct assembly.

Comment: hi @SimplyGed feel free to write in answer, and I can send points, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to know of a Type that is in the assembly.

Let's say `App.MyClass` is defined in the assembly. You can use reflection to get the location of the assembly containing that type:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(App.MyClass)).Location.
```

You can't do it using a namespace as a namespace can exist across multiple assemblies.

Or utilize

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```